# One form field alone fails to display value from database

Tags: python, django

My model:

```
class DirectoryDoctors (models.Model):
    num = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    design_choices = (
        ('IMO', 'IMO'),
        ('AIMO', 'AIMO'),
        ('Dental Surgeon', 'Dental Surgeon'),
        ('Regional Deputy Director', 'Regional Deputy Director'),
        ('Joint Director', 'Joint Director'),
        ('Director', 'Director'),
        ('unspecified', 'Unspecified')
    )
    designation = models.CharField(
        choices=design_choices, max_length=30, default='unspecified')
    mobile = models.CharField(max_length=15, default='')
    alternate = models.CharField(max_length=15, default='', blank=True)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=50, default='', blank=True)
    dob = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    specialiast_or_not_choices = (
        ('Yes', 'Yes'),
        ('No', 'No'),
        ('Unspecified', 'Unspecified')
    )
    specialiast = models.CharField(
        choices=specialiast_or_not_choices, max_length=30, default='Unspecified')
    specialty_choices = (
        ('Internal Medicine', 'Internal Medicine'),
        ('General Surgery', 'General Surgery'),
        ('ENT', 'ENT'),
        ('Ophthalmology', 'Ophthalmology'),
        ('Dermatology', 'Dermatology'),
        ('Paediatrics', 'Paediatrics'),
        ('Respiratory Medicine', 'Respiratory Medicine'),
        ('Psychiatry', 'Psychiatry'),
        ('Obstetrics and Gynaecology', 'Obstetrics and Gynaecology'),
        ('Physical Medicine', 'Physical Medicine'),
        ('Radiodiagnosis', 'Radiodiagnosis'),
        ('Anaesthesia', 'Anaesthesia'),
        ('Unspecified', 'Unspecified'),
        ('Not Applicable', 'Not Applicable')
    )
    specialty = models.CharField(
        choices=specialty_choices, max_length=30, default='Unspecified')
    institution = models.ForeignKey(DirectoryHospital, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    bloodgroup_choices = (('apos', 'A+'),
        ('A-', 'A-'),
        ('B+', 'B+'),
        ('B-', 'B-'),
        ('O+', 'O+'),
        ('O-', 'O-'),
        ('AB+', 'AB+'),
        ('AB-', 'AB-'),
        ('-', '-')
        )
    bloodgroup = models.CharField(choices=bloodgroup_choices, max_length=15, blank=True)
    spousename = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    children = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    present_address = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    permanent_address = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ["name", "mobile", "email"]
```

My form:

```
class DirectoryDoctorsForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = DirectoryDoctors
        fields = [
            'name',
            'designation',
            'mobile',
            'alternate',
            'email',
            'dob',
            'specialiast',
            'specialty',
            'institution',
            'bloodgroup',
            'spousename',
            'children',
            'present_address',
            'permanent_address'
            ]
        unique_together = ["name", "mobile", "email"]
```

My view:

```
@login_required
def editdoctorprofile(request, person_id):
    person_id = int(person_id)
    doc = DirectoryDoctors.objects.get(num = person_id)
    msg =''
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print("POST details", request.POST)
        form = DirectoryDoctorsForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            print("Form is valid.")
            username = request.POST.get('username')
        else:
            msg = "Invalid details."
            print(msg)
    else:
        form = DirectoryDoctorsForm(instance=doc)

    return render(
        request, 'app/editdoctor.html', {
            'rnd_num': randomnumber(),
            'doc': doc,
            'form': form                                                                
        })
```

app/editdoctor.html:

```
<form method="post">
{% csrf_token %}

<div class="row my-1">
    <div class="col-md-2 mb-6">
        <label for="name">Name</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-18 mb-6">
        {{ form.name|add_class:"form-control" }}
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row my-1">
    <div class="col-md-2 mb-6">
        <label for="designation">Designation</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-18 mb-6">
        {{ form.designation|add_class:"form-control" }}
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row my-1">
    <div class="col-md-2 mb-6">
        <label for="mobile">Mobile</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-18 mb-6">
        {{ form.mobile|add_class:"form-control" }}
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row my-1">
    <div class="col-md-2 mb-6">
        <label for="designation">Alternate</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-18 mb-6">
        {{ form.alternate|add_class:"form-control" }}
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row my-1">
    <div class="col-md-5 mb-6">
        <label for="specialiast">Are you a Specialiast?</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-15 mb-6">
        {{ form.specialiast|add_class:"form-control" }}
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row my-1">
    <div class="col-md-6 mb-6">
        <label for="specialty">If yes, what is your Specialty?</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-14 mb-6">
        {{ form.specialty|add_class:"form-control" }}
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row my-1">
    <div class="col-md-2 mb-6">
        <label for="institution">Station</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-18 mb-6">
        {{ form.institution|add_class:"form-control" }}
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row my-1">
    <div class="col-md-3 mb-6">
        <label for="bloodgroup">Blood Group</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-17 mb-6">
        {{ form.bloodgroup|add_class:"form-control" }}
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row my-1">
    <div class="col-md-5 mb-6">
        <label for="spousename">Name of your spouse</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-15 mb-6">
        {{ form.spousename|add_class:"form-control" }}
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row my-1">
    <div class="col-md-5 mb-6">
        <label for="children">Name of your children</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-15 mb-6">
        {{ form.children|add_class:"form-control" }}
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row my-1">
    <div class="col-md-4 mb-6">
        <label for="present_address">Present Address</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-16 mb-6">
        {{ form.present_address|add_class:"form-control" }}
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row my-1">
    <div class="col-md-4 mb-6">
        <label for="permanent_address">Permanent Address</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-16 mb-6">
        {{ form.permanent_address|add_class:"form-control" }}
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 mb-1">
        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block" id="add_doctor" type="submit">Save changes</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

When this page is displayed, for example for a queryset get for pk of 175, the form field bloodgroup alone is not displayed correctly. It shows the value "-------"

But if on the django shell, I do:

```
>>> from app.models import DirectoryDoctors,DirectoryHospital
>>> DirectoryDoctors.objects.get(pk=175)
<DirectoryDoctors: Mike Dewey, Deputy Director, Deputy Directorate Angamaly, Angamaly>
>>> DirectoryDoctors.objects.get(pk=175).bloodgroup
'A+'
>>>
```

Why is this field alone not properly displayed?

Comment: One thing I like to mention is that, `form = DirectoryDoctorsForm(request.POST)` and `form.save()` will create new instance instead of editing the existing one. To update existing instance, you need pass it through form like `form = DirectoryDoctorsForm(request.POST, instance=doc)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the field has an invalid value.

You defined the first choice of the field `bloodgroup` as:

```
bloodgroup_choices = (
    ('apos', 'A+'),
    ...
)
```

But when printing the value, it shows `A+` (as you showed us):

```
>>> DirectoryDoctors.objects.get(pk=175).bloodgroup
'A+'
```

but it has to be `apos` for the widget to recognize it in the HTML form

---

This method call should highlight the issue, if you try it with your data:

```
>>> DirectoryDoctors.objects.get(pk=175).get_bloodgroup_display()
```

Comment: More likely, OP should update the `apos` choice, since all the other options are the same as the display value.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Yeah, you're right, that would probably better for future maintenability of the code base...